# How to search in another table in Laravel with Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models:

```
Order
Customer
```

I have `customer_id` in `orders` table. Customer details (name, phone, email etc) in `customers`table. But I am writing query for orders table.

Now, I want to search with Customer Name on Orders but in Orders table I just have `customer_id`.

How will I link up with customers table so that I can search with Customer Name. I want to do that with Eloquent.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing relationship filtering with Eloquent.

You can achieve it with `whereHas` or using an advanced join / left join query.

I suggest you do a research about Eloquent filtering on Laravel documentation, everything you need for your task should be there.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#advanced-join-clauses

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create relationship in the orders model, you can use either `belongsTo` or `hasOne` relationship.

**belongsTo relationship will be like as below**

```
public function customer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ustomer::class, 'foreign Key', 'id');
}
```

**and the hasOne relationship will be like as below**

```
public function customer()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Customer::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

**The search function will be like as below**

```
public function OrderSearch(Request $request){
   try {

     /**
      * Fetching data with orders relationship
      */
     $orders = OrdersModel::with(['customer'])

     if(!empty($request->search)){
        /**
         * Searching the name key inside
         * the customer relationship
         */
        $orders->where(fn($query)=>
            $query->whereHas('customer',fn($query2) => 
                    $query2->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%'));
         );
     }

     /**
      * Returning the response
      */
     return $orders->get();

 } catch (\Throwable $th) {
     throw $th;
 }
}
```

Kindly refer the laravel eloquent-relationships documentation : [eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

In models define relationships

Customer model

```
public function orders()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Orders::class);
}
```

Order model

```
public function customer()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(ustomer::class, 'foreign Key', 'id');
}
```

Then you can call relationships and search what you want
`Customer::whereHas('orders')`